# Can't Get New Intel Denoiser to Work on Projects

Tags: denoise

I've been following along on all the tutorials I can find to make this happen, but my denoiser node doesn't seem to have any effect whatsoever when I apply it. Where am I going wrong? Thanks in advance for the help!

Here is the .blend file:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to plug the "image" output of the denoiser into the "image" input of the compositor.

Remove the link from "image" output of "Render layers" entirely.

Loaded it up, and it works flawlessly.
FYI: The intel denoiser doesn't kick in until after the image is fully rendered, and takes 3-5 seconds to clear it up.

Comment: Wait, so it did work when you loaded it up initially meaning I had it right? Or it worked after you made those changes?

Comment: I guess I'm confused because as soon as anybody in the tutorials ads it in, it completely gets rid of the grain. I have a relatively fast computer (i7 6700K, 1080GTX) and even after letting it sit for a bit I still seeing visible artifacts, even after applying your changes.

Comment: These are the tutorials I'm watching: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Pw-OxOHHu5I (1:28 for Denoise)

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8PpFaR3mD3g&t=45s (2:07)

Comment: You're going to need to increase your sample count. Denoisers allow you to use fewer samples, but it's not magic and has its limits.

Comment: Oh, and check if your *Image Viewer* is on *Render Layer* or *Viewer Node.* Bit self-explanatory, but if it's on *Render Layer*, you won't see the change until you rerun the render.

Comment: Ok I am seeing it now, My problem is I would CTRL+SHIFT+LMB on the Render Layer node and wait and it wouldn't do anything, then I wouldn't wait long enough when doing that to the denoise node. Once I do that and wait long enough it does denoise.Thank you all for your input!

Comment: Please add an illustration of the nodes and how to connect them, so that other users can learn from this answer as well.

Answer (score 2):

Just to illustrate how to connect the *Denoise node* in *Compositor*.

[image]

Comment: Awesome, thank you for posting this!

Comment: Happy to help :). I'd also suggest [this video by CG Cookie](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fONxsfY9nO0) explaining the Denoise node in more depth.