# Emission light creates grainy and blurry shadow

Tags: rendering, light, blur, emission

I encountered a problem with emission light and shadow I get after rendering. Namely, I create the cell light as you can see in screenshot, and gave them emission material as light source. Also, I create reflection background plate.

I tried everything in Cycles mode of rendering...without Denoising (I get really grainy render), with Denoising default setup (grainy effect just get blurred but it's still visible)...increasing the Radius value to max (I get combination of grainy and blurry render).

[image]

Any suggestion, what to change to get clear photo realistic image?

Thanks.

Comment: Hello :). Please add the number of samples you used, and your Blender version. Just to narrow down possible problems. Thank you.

Comment: Up your samples to a minimum of 400 (which is still pretty low) and try intel's denoiser: [Can't Get New Intel Denoiser to Work on Projects](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/163160/31447)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to avoid noisy renders in Cycles?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/4980/how-to-avoid-noisy-renders-in-cycles)

Comment: Thank you for suggestions...I tried with 512 render samples but I didn't get much better render. Blender version is 2.81a. Also, with denoiser I get those blurry artifacts...

Comment: By using intel's denoiser? @Igor Really? Should work. Otherwise I suggest upload a simplified file (without the furniture) to https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/ and I'll give it a shot...

Comment: 2min, 512 samples, area lights, intel denoiser: https://i.stack.imgur.com/TJdOj.jpg

Comment: Hm, well...I'm not sure it's a Intel's denoiser, but some denoiser is :). It's denoising option in View layer properties...

I'll appreciate if you can help me with this....here is the file:
[<img src="https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/embedImage.png?bid=9Z0ESad0" />](https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/9Z0ESad0/)

Comment: Wrong one... how the intel denoiser looks like: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ErAlu.png at 512 samples (and missing textures), Have a look into my file: https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/jj2smmpy

Comment: To answer your question: the artefacts are coming from the denoiser in combination with a too low sample count (32, you would need 800+) as explained in the answers of the linked duplicate, again here: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/4980/how-to-avoid-noisy-renders-in-cycles BTW: You might want to add a *Portal Light* for the window to optimize render times.

Comment: Thank you so much!!! I'm new in Blender but I've use some other 3D modeling app (Solidworks, Modo)...anyhow, I'ts always better to ask than to loose couple of hours to figure out how things works.... :)